# Session architecture: single site-wide object

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, session-variables

Is it okay to store session variables all in single object? Any disadvantages?

```
XSessionData SessionData
{
    get
    {
        string key = "XSessionData";
        if (HttpContext.Current == null)
            return null;
        if (HttpContext.Current.Session == null)
            return null;
        object data = HttpContext.Current.Session[key];
        if (data == null)
            HttpContext.Current.Session[key] = data = new XSessionData();
        return (XSessionData)data;
    }
}
```

Comment: I would re-phrase the question so it is not opinion-based.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no technical reason why you cannot do that.  It can be good practice if the items in session are related to one another.  I could see that the above pattern could be useful if you are unit testing code that relies on `Session`.

However, you should use `Session` as least as possible.  And you should designate classes that manipulate the `Session` so that it doesn't turn into global state that is changed all over the place.

However, keep in mind that session storage could change.  For example, some objects will work fine in memory, but not work in database session storage.

For database session storage, any object that is saved in session must be `Serializable`.